# How do I fix ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException errors when accessing a single data from multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, vector

I'm making a typing game with a Java GUI.
I get these errors intermittently.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0
    at java.base/java.util.Vector.get(Vector.java:781)
    at GamePanel$DetectBottomThread.run(GamePanel.java:200)
```

And GamePanel.java:200 line is

```
int y = ((JLabel)targetVector.get(i)).getY();
```

in **DetectBottomThread.**

This tis my code(important methods)

```
    public GamePanel(ScorePanel scorePanel, EditPanel editPanel) {
        // 기억해둔다.
        this.scorePanel = scorePanel;
        this.editPanel = editPanel;

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(gameGroundPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        input.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER); // input JTextField 가운데정렬
        input.setFont(new Font("Aharoni", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        
        // textfield에서 enter
        input.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JTextField t = (JTextField)(e.getSource());
                String inWord = t.getText(); // 사용자가 입력한 단어
                for (int i=0; i < targetVector.size(); i++) {
                    String text = targetVector.get(i).getText();
                    if(text.equals(inWord)) { // 단어맞추기 성공
                        // 점수 올리기
                        scorePanel.increase();
                        scorePanel.repaintScore();
                        gameGroundPanel.remove(targetVector.get(i)); // 패널에서 라벨 떼기
                        targetVector.remove(i); // targetVector에서 삭제
                        t.setText(null); // input 비우기
                    }
                    // 벡터 마지막원소에서도 일치하는 단어 못찾음
                    if((i == (targetVector.size() - 1)) && !targetVector.get(i).getText().equals(inWord)) {
                        scorePanel.decrease();
                        scorePanel.repaintScore();
                        t.setText(null);
                    }
                    t.requestFocus(); // 엔터 친 후에도 textField에 focus유지
                }
                
            }
        });
    }
```

```
public void gameStart() {
        // 단어생성
        generateWordThread.start();
        // 단어 떨어뜨리기
        dropWordThread.start();
        // 땅에 닿은 단어 감지
        detectBottomThread.start();
    }
    
    // 단어 생성하는 스레드
    // 정해진 시간마다 단어를 계속 생성한다.....
    // 생성한 단어는 별도의 스레드를 두어 아래로 내려가도록 한다.
    public class GenerateWordThread extends Thread{
        
        private Vector<JLabel>targetVector = null;
        
        synchronized void generateWord() {
            JLabel targetLabel = new JLabel("");
            // 단어 한 개 선택
            String newWord = textSource.get();
            targetLabel.setText(newWord);
            
            
            // targetLabel 모양
            targetLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER); // JLabel 가운데정렬
            targetLabel.setSize(200, 40);
            targetLabel.setFont(new Font("Aharoni", Font.PLAIN, 20));
            
            // x좌표 랜덤 설정
            int startX = (int) (Math.random()*gameGroundPanel.getWidth());
            while(true) {
                if ((startX + targetLabel.getWidth()) > gameGroundPanel.getWidth()) 
                    startX = (int) (Math.random()*gameGroundPanel.getWidth());
                else
                    break;
            }
            
            targetLabel.setLocation(startX,0);
            
            targetLabel.setOpaque(false); // 배경 투명하게
            targetVector.addElement(targetLabel); // targetVector에 생성한 newWord 추가
            gameGroundPanel.add(targetLabel);
        }
        
        public GenerateWordThread(Vector<JLabel>targetVector) {
            this.targetVector = targetVector;
        }
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                generateWord();
                gameGroundPanel.repaint();
                try {
                    sleep(6000);
                    //time -= 500; // 시간 점점 빨라지게 하기 위해
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } // end of while
        } // end of run()
    } // end of GenerateWordThread
    
    // 단어 아래로 내리는 스레드
    public class DropWordThread extends Thread{
        
        private Vector<JLabel>targetVector = null;
        
        public DropWordThread(Vector<JLabel>targetVector) {
            this.targetVector = targetVector;
        }
        
        // targetVector에 들어있는 모든 JLabel들의 y좌표 증가
        @Override
        public void run() {
             while (true){
                 for (int i=0; i<targetVector.size(); i++) {
                    int x = targetVector.get(i).getX();
                    int y = targetVector.get(i).getY();
                    targetVector.get(i).setLocation(x, y+5);
                    gameGroundPanel.repaint();
                } // end of for
                 try {
                        sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            } // end of while
        } // end of run()
    } // end of DropWordThread
    
    public class DetectBottomThread extends Thread {
        
        private Vector<JLabel>targetVector = null;
        
        public DetectBottomThread(Vector<JLabel>targetVector) {
            this.targetVector = targetVector;
        }
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                for(int i=0; i<targetVector.size(); i++) {
                    int y = ((JLabel)targetVector.get(i)).getY(); // 오류가 자?꾸만..
                    if (y > gameGroundPanel.getHeight()-20) {
                        scorePanel.decreaseLife();
                        gameGroundPanel.remove(targetVector.get(i)); // 패널에서 라벨 떼기
                        targetVector.remove(i); // targetVector에서 삭제
                    }
                }
            } // end of while
        } // end of run()
    }// end of Thread
        
    }
```

I don't know how to solve this problem because Vector's element was approached simultaneously by many threads.

I wonder if I have to use a different data type than Vector or if there is a solution to using Synchronized method. (I know the concept of the Synchronized Method, but I haven't found a way to solve this problem using it.)

I am very sorry that the source code is long and the annotation is Korean. Thank you

Comment: Try out [Synchronization of ArrayList in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/synchronization-arraylist-java/) and let us know if it solves your problem.

Comment: I know how to synchronize methods, but is there a way to synchronize objects only? I don't know how to use the Syncronize block.